# Team Build cannot copy diagnostic activity log to the drop location

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm trying to configure a new install of Team Foundation Server Express. The problem I'm having is that when I run a build that outputs to a drop folder I get the error

> An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: Access to the path '\\c$\drops\Test Application\Test Application_20130206.9\Logs' is denied.

If I disable the drop folder the build runs fine.

The drop folder is located on the same machine as TFS. I've given full control of that folder to the NETWORK SERVICE account. Are there any additional accounts that need access to this folder or any additional steps I need to take to allow drops?

Thanks!

Comment: Try actually creating a share rather than going through c$.

Comment: You should really try to rephrase your question here. I was searching for something related to disabling the drop folder copy and stumbled on you question. The title does not point to what you actually want to know, and you should probably answer it yourself too or ask @EricSpeelman to do it so that it is not considered 'unanswered'.