# TFS Build fails on Specifying Drop folder location

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I'm having merely same issue as in [Team Build cannot copy diagnostic activity log to the drop location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735496/team-foundation-server), but couldn't resolve the issue.

TFS is installed in our server and build agents are created over there. And i'm accessing TFS in my dev machine as an admin, and created a new Build Definition. I created a Drop folder(Shared to Everyone) in my dev machine(DEV1) Path: \DEV1\Drops.

The Build is getting succeeded when the drop folder path is not specified. But it fails when i provide the drop folder's path \DEV1\Drops. and i'm getting the following error.

```
  Exception Message: TF270016: An error occurred publishing log files from 
    'C:\Builds\1\TFS_Process\Project_for_TFS_Build\src\Main\Project_for_TFS.log' to 
    '\\DEV1\Drops\Project_for_TFS_Build\Project_for_TFS_Build_20131112.2\logs'. Details: The 
    network path was not found.
```

Comment: I suppose you meant `\\DEV1\Drops`?

Comment: @Torbjörn Bergstedt Yes, i did put \\, but it is not getting displayed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get it work, but not exactly. Why is,

- I created the drop folder in the server where TFS is installed and it works.
- There is some network issue connecting Client machine to server, due to which i didn't manage to create the drop folder to get it work.